# Shipping Rates on Magento - up to 20kg and over 20kg

Tags: shipping, magento-community

I have a Magento installation running Magento Community.  I need to set up shipping classes based on a weight system.  Any item up to the weight of 20kg needs to be £5.00GBP for delivery, anything over 20kg needs to be £29.99GBP for delivery.

Currently the site is running shipping so that every 1kg is £5.00GBP but everything over 20kg is £29.99GBP so I have a slight problem with it, its also adding shipping for every item and not a total weight on the cart.

Is it possible to do the above at all?

Any help would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the tablerates functionality that magento offers by default.

Just go to `System->Configuration->Shipping Methods->Table Rates`.
Change the config scope to your website (from the top left selector).
Set the `Condition` field to `Weight vs Destination`.
Download the CSV with the rates and fill in something like this:

```
Country Region/State "Zip/Postal Code"  "Order Subtotal (and above)" "Shipping Price"
*       *             *                  0.0000                       5.0000
*       *             *                  20.0000                      29.9900
```

Reupload you file and enjoy.